# how we can manage if child categories having multiple parent category in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Suppose if i have a menu like 
HOME| RECIPES| VIDEOS | CHEFS

And in (recipes Tab) i am showing some categories and sub-categories.
The same categories and sub-categories i want in videos tab.Like what i want is:
i would assign some videos post to the same category and some normal post to the same category.When i go on the site and come from Recipes Tab and click some category(Can we get the value of parent tab menu that we are clicking this category , and coming from that tab). is this possible.

if not , can it be possible that, if i assign some video post and some article posts to the same category but once i click on tab RECIPES, it will list only article posts AND when i click on VIDEOS tab , it will list out all video posts.

Comment: You might have better luck on the wordpress stackexchange.  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what you mean. You can use the following plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multi-level-navigation-plugin/screenshots